# How to use predicate method in many to many relation entity framework linq lambda expression?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, predicate, lambda

My problem is hard to solve. i need your help this problem. There is many to many relation in codefirst. But i can not resolve this. i would like to use Predicate func. But i can not resolve it? how to use "Method(Predicate func)"

```
     public int Method<T>(Predicate<T> func)
    {


        var s1 = this.Uow.X.GetAll().Where(func)
                       .SelectMany(a => a.OrganizationalUnits.Where(q => Identity.Y.Contains(q.Z)))
                      .GroupBy(t => t, (k, g) => new
                      {
                          Tag = k,
                          Count = g.Count()
                      })
                      .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count);


        var s2 = this.Uow.X.GetAll().Where(func)
                        .SelectMany(a => a.Classes.Where(q => Identity.Y.Contains(q.K)))
                        .GroupBy(t => t, (k, g) => new
                        {
                            Tag = k,
                            Count = g.Count()
                        })
                        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count);


        var s3 = this.Uow.X.GetAll().Where(func)
                        .SelectMany(a => a.Courses.Where(q => Identity.Y.Contains(q.L)))
                        .GroupBy(t => t, (k, g) => new
                        {
                            Tag = k,
                            Count = g.Count()
                        })
                        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count);



        return s1.ToString().Count() + s2.ToString().Count() + s3.ToString().Count();
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you have here and what you are asking...

Comment: Does your method GetAll return an IEnumerable, or an IQueryable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way to do it.  I also removed the `ToString()`s on the last line since you don't need an object to be a string to count it.

Call like this:   `int result = Method<TypeGoesHere>(p => p == aValue);`

```
 public int Method<T>(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> Predicate)
{


    var s1 = this.Uow.X.GetAll().Where(Predicate)
                   .SelectMany(a => a.OrganizationalUnits.Where(q => Identity.Y.Contains(q.Z)))
                  .GroupBy(t => t, (k, g) => new
                  {
                      Tag = k,
                      Count = g.Count()
                  })
                  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count);


    var s2 = this.Uow.X.GetAll().Where(Predicate)
                    .SelectMany(a => a.Classes.Where(q => Identity.Y.Contains(q.K)))
                    .GroupBy(t => t, (k, g) => new
                    {
                        Tag = k,
                        Count = g.Count()
                    })
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count);


    var s3 = this.Uow.X.GetAll().Where(Predicate)
                    .SelectMany(a => a.Courses.Where(q => Identity.Y.Contains(q.L)))
                    .GroupBy(t => t, (k, g) => new
                    {
                        Tag = k,
                        Count = g.Count()
                    })
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count);

    return s1.Count() + s2.Count() + s3.Count();
}
```

I think you probably want an extension method for whatever type `this` is.  It would look like this (if `thisType` was type of `this`).  This does not need to be a template since you (but not me) know the type of `X.GetAll()`.  I'm guessing List`<int>` which would make T int.  I've also changed the code to be briefer but have the same functionality.  (It might be your original code was doing the wrong thing but this does the same thing.)

Call like this:

```
thisType something = new something();
someType aValue = X; // don't know the type here.

// do stuff with something

int result = something.Method(p => p == aValue);
```

Code:

```
public static int Method(this thisType me, Expression<Func<someType, Boolean>> Predicate)
{
    var allOfEm = me.Uow.X.GetAll().Where(Predicate);

    var s1 = allOfEm
              .SelectMany(a => a.OrganizationalUnits.Where(q => Identity.Y.Contains(q.Z)))
              .Distinct();

    var s2 = allOfEm
              .SelectMany(a => a.Classes.Where(q => Identity.Y.Contains(q.K)))
              .Distinct();

    var s3 = allOfEm
              .SelectMany(a => a.Courses.Where(q => Identity.Y.Contains(q.L)))
              .Distinct();

    return s1.Count() + s2.Count() + s3.Count();
}
```